# Displaying time in JSON file on JS Timeline

Tags: javascript, json, time, timeline

I am working on developing a widget using this timeline JS template. I have to be able to receive events in JSON format. For now, I am just working on receiving them from a local file. I am able to receive events that include the date, however I am having trouble getting the time to work. The suggestions that I have found do not seem to be working. Can anyone help?

Here is my JSON test file:

```
"events": 
[{
"start": "2013-03-18", //need to add time here
"end": "2014-03-18",
"title": "test a",
"color": "green",
"description": "this is a test",
"image": "",
"link": ""
},

...

]}
```

Comment: Thank you, Lee! I got it to work. It was a matter of the incorrect dateTimeFormat. I am new to this site, is there a way I can help your reputation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical date format is "yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss.mmm" and these can be passed to a javascript new Date(x) constructor (where 'x' is) but some browsers don't like that format. They want / instead of - and a 'T' where that blank separates the date and time. See this:

[Highcharts: x-value as date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327326/highcharts-x-value-as-date/16327464#16327464)

For more details you can look at this [FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/leemeador/mBMJF/)

One way to do it which is shown there seems to work in lots of browsers:

```
var d = '2013-04-30 00:00:00';
var date = new Date(d.replace(' ', 'T') + 'Z')
```