# globalization - Need help to manipulate dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, gmt

Hi we're using jqwidgets Grid and all dates values retrieved from database are showing one day before that real value is, but if we put 3 more hours in the value the day value is correct. We assume that problem is based in the -3 hours GTM of Argentina time zone. Somebody known how to configure jQuery globalize to set GMT -3?. Thanks!

Comment: What is the time zone setting on the clock in the computer you are running it on?

Comment: UTC-03:00 Buenos Aires

Comment: Do the dates in the database have time zone info stored with each date?

Comment: We have values like 2011-08-23 00:00:00.000 and the column datatype is datetime. Can you tell me some way to check if these values hvae time zone info?. Thanks.

Comment: That is just date and time of day. The time zone is assumed. There is some info here about taking a string and turning it into a javascript date: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327326/highcharts-x-value-as-date/16327464#16327464 You need to either add the "Z" on the end or not, most likely.

Comment: This issue is about explorer configuration or computer configuration?

Comment: It's possibly just the way you are converting those time strings from the database to javascript dates. If when converting they are taken as UTC, then conversion to a string via javascript (including globalize) will generate the corresponding date/time in Buenos Aires timezone. If you can let those database strings be converted to javascript Date objects as local time, it should be ok.

Comment: Maybe you could post the code that converts the database dates to javascript Date objects.

Answer (score 0):

Use a utility function to do this:

```
function timeZone(date, offset, sign)
  {
  var isoDate = new Date(date).toISOString().replace("Z", sign + "0" + offset +":00");
  return isoDate;
  }

new Date(timeZone("2011-01-01", 3, "-") ).toString()
new Date(timeZone("2011-01-01", 3, "+") ).toString()
```

**References**

- [ECMAScript 2015: Date.prototype.toISOString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.toisostring)
- [ECMAScript 2015: Date-Time String Format](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-date-time-string-format)